# Height Issue with Flexslider in IE

Tags: jquery, flexslider

If you go to this page https://www.bingomum.co.uk/sites/bgo/ in IE 11 you should see that when the page is loaded the container for the slider has a height about double of what it should be. No other browser does this and the height updates to the correct height after I click around on the page or re-size the window. I have done a lot of searching and tried a few things that I found, but nothing seems to work. I even tried having a static height for the container, however the CSS only worked in other browsers. The CSS didn't even show up when inspecting the element in IE.

Is there maybe a way to run whatever code is ran to update the height after the page is done loading? I figure that the height updates when re-sizing the window or clicking the page, so there must be a function I can run after page load.

Here is a link to a side by side screenshot of the issue. The 2 browsers are Chrome and IE 11.
http://s7.postimg.org/qtkimpodn/Untitled.png

Comment: If you have a problem with a certain browser you should always also tell with which version of the browser. Especially if it is about IE. Beside that you should show a minimal working example in the question and not just link to the page.

Comment: OK I added my version of IE to my post, IE 11. I also added a link to a side by side screenshot of the issue. The 2 browsers are Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

You get the height issues with Flexslider in IE when you use lazy loading.

Lazy loading hides the image address when Flexslider is checking for the height of the pictures.

Solution: 
Instead of having empty src values, use the image src of the first slide for all following slides as well.

Lazy loading will replace the src values like before.